# BQ Partitioning by column instead of date

Tags: google-bigquery, partitioning

I'm trying to partition my tables in BQ, I've read the documentation and it always points to timePartition. I understand that this may be the default partition, but is it possible to define your table's column/s as the partition?

Any inputs would help. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not as of today. The only available partition type is "DAY"

Comment: Thanks for the quick feedback.

Comment: We expect to provide this ability in the coming months. I will provide another update as we get closer to the launch.

Comment: Great! Will be looking forward to that feature. Thank you for the heads up. :)